# calling multiple functions to main issue

Tags: python, function

Okay, so I am having a little issue with calling 4 function to the main. I have been sitting here for over an hour and cannot figure it out.

I keep on getting this error:

`(total) = total(num, num2)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment`

```
def main():

    num = float(input(" Enter a number: "))
    num2 = float(input(" Enter another number: "))

    (total) = total(num, num2)
    (diff) = difference(num, num2)
    (product) = product(num, num2)
    (quot) = quotient(num, num2)

    print(" The total is: ", format(total, ".1f"), sep="")
    print(" The difference is: ", format(diff, ".1f"), sep="")
    print(" The product is: ", format(product, ".2f"), sep="")
    print(" The quotient is: ", format(quot, ".2f"), sep="")

def total(num, num2):
    total = (num + num2)
    return(total)


def difference(num, num2):
    diff = abs(num - num2)
    return(diff)


def product(num, num2):
    product = num * num2
    return(product)


def quotient(num, num2):
    quot = num / num2
    return(quot)

main()
```

Comment: Tag language and format your code.

Comment: Why do you think it is a good idea to call a function named X and store the result in a variable named X (```total = total()```)? Of course that won't work. And what do you think ```(X) = something``` is doing (regarding the extra brackets)?

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. You cannot call a function when the viariable in that function has the same name. (tot) = total(num, num2) is calling a variable from the total function if i am correct. Appreciate the input.

Comment: `tot = total(num, num2)` calls the function `total`, hands over `num` and `num2` as parameters and assigns the return value of `toatal` to `tot`.

Comment: BTW, you have kind of a "parentheses overflow". You don't have to write `(x) = function(1, 2)`, just `x = function(1, 2)` is enough. The same applies to your `return` statements. They are _statements_, not _functions_ so please use `return value` and not `return (value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function describes what you are trying to do, there is no reason to create local variables in your functions if you won't even use them.

```
def total(num, num2):
    return num+num2

def difference(num, num2):
    return abs(num - num2)

def product(num, num2):
    return num*num2

def quotient(num, num2):
    return num/num2

def main():
    num = float(input(" Enter a number: "))
    num2 = float(input(" Enter another number: "))

    summa = total(num, num2) #try to not use the same name for a variable and a function
    diff = difference(num, num2)
    prod = product(num, num2)
    quot = quotient(num, num2)

    print(" The total is: ", format(summa, ".1f"), sep="")
    print(" The difference is: ", format(diff, ".1f"), sep="")
    print(" The product is: ", format(prod, ".2f"), sep="")
    print(" The quotient is: ", format(quot, ".2f"), sep="")

main()
```